# Responsive design not triggering whenever adjusting from JQuery

Tags: jquery

How come my responsive design isn't triggering whenever there are changes made in JQuery?

For example when I edit the width:
[jsfiddle.net/odsotmpr/](http://jsfiddle.net/odsotmpr/)

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

```
$(".test").click(function()
{
    $(this).css('width', '200px');
});
```

```
.test
{
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 820px) {
    .test
    {
        width: 70px;
    }
}
```

I tried using `!important` for the responsive width, but then again, if I want to change the width programmatically (through JQuery) it won't be possible.

Comment: even `!important` should never override an inline style. What were you trying?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well, i'm trying to create a 'hover' effect for whenever I hover the item. The hover effect basically increases the width & height. But the website is also responsive for other devices. So the problem i'm currently facing is that whenever responsive design is triggered I cannot 'call' my hover effect.

Comment: If you're wanting a hover effect to only change height and width, why not use `:hover` in CSS, that way your media query isn't overridden by depending on javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inline styles will always take precedence over css rules. It may be best to make another css class instead.

Like this:

Javascript

```
$(".test").click(function()
{
    $(this).addClass("clicked")
});
```

Css:

```
.test
{
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
}

.clicked{
    width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 820px) {
    .test
    {
        width: 70px !important;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DarthDerrr/odsotmpr/1/

Edit - since the width is dynamic, a window resize handler could be used instead:
In that case, (I really don't like using listeners to window.resize for performance reasons), but something like this is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/DarthDerrr/odsotmpr/2/ - using a window.resize handler - but this is only if absolutely necessary of course.

Comment: I tried this method, but couldn't figure out how to add an 'attribute' to the class I made (since I have to calculate the width & height).

Comment: I said only if necessary because the window resize listener may degrade performance if your page has a lot going on.  One way to lessen that is to debounce the window resize handler.

Answer (score 0):

Changing styles with javascript puts the style inline in the HTML, which overrides anything you may have in your CSS.  In order to work around this, instead of applying a style directly through javascript, you can add a class with the appropriate styling:

**CSS**

```
.clicked {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".test").click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```